# A die is rolled 5 times, what is the probability that there are exactly 2 fives?

Tags: probability

A die is rolled 5 times. 
Determine the probability that there are exactly 2 fives. The answer should be a decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at one possible way:

$$x_1, 5, x_2, 5, x_3$$

The $x_i$ stand for "anything else but 5." The probability of this event is $(\frac{1}{6})^2(\frac{5}{6})^3$. So, it can happen in this particular way OR (this is the key word) another way corresponding to *all the other ways to arrange the fives*. How many ways are there to arrange two objects in a set of five?

The answer is $\binom {5}{3}$. Hence, the probability of your event is $$\binom {5}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3.$$

Answer (score 2):

The total number of combinations is $6^5$. To get a combination with exactly 2 fives, there are $1\times1\times5\times5\times5=5^3$ ways of arranging the dice if the first two dice are fives. Multiply that by the number of ways of arranging the two fives amongst the 5 dice - $\binom{5}{2}=\frac{5!}{2!\cdot3!}=10$. Thus, $$\binom{5}{2}\cdot\frac{5^3}{6^5}\approx0.161$$ Is the proportion of throws that will have exactly 2 fives.

Answer (score 1):

If you require two specific times(e.g. first time and second time) to be 5(probability $1/6$), others to be non-5(probability $1-1/6=5/6$). The probabiliy is $(1/6)^2(5/6)^3$, you have $C^5_2=10$ different ways to roll two 5. Therefore the answer is $10(1/6)^2(5/6)^3$, which is approximately 0.1608.